# How to get different parsed JSON data?

Tags: arduino-uno, node.js, json

In my recent project, I have to parse incoming JSON data in Arduino and I successfully did it. But it is only for one constant data string.

For example, if my incoming JSON string like:

```
{"TPS":"0.40","MAP":"0.95","LOAD":"14"}
```

And Arduino code for parsing this data is below:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

String response = "";
bool begin = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() { 
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
  while(Serial.available() || !begin) {
    char in = Serial.read();
    if (in == '{') {
      begin = true;
    }
    if(begin) {
      response += (in);
    }
    if(in == '}') {
        break;
    }
    delay(1);
  }
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
  String TPS = root["TPS"];
  String MAP = root["MAP"];
  String LOAD = root["LOAD"];
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(TPS);
  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(MAP);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(LOAD);  
}
```

Then the output looks like:

```
TPS  : 0.40
MAP  : 0.95
LOAD : 14
```

That's fine, but when the incoming JSON string changes, what should I do?

Suppose the incoming JSON string looks like:

```
{"LOAD":"2.40","RPM":"4200","INJECTION_TIME":"4.87"}
```

Because I have to handle both incoming JSON strings, I can't replace any part like:

```
  String LOAD = root["LOAD"];
  String RPM = root["RPM"];
  String INJECTION_TIME = root["INJECTION_TIME"];
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(LOAD);
  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(RPM);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(INJECTION_TIME);
```

Instead of

```
  String TPS = root["TPS"];
  String MAP = root["MAP"];
  String LOAD = root["LOAD"];
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(TPS);
  lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
  lcd.print(MAP);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(LOAD);
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just `jsonBuffer.parse(Serial)`?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Means? I can't understand what you mean? Is this catch Serial data and parse it? Something like that?

Comment: My question is: Why did you choose to not use `jsonBuffer.parse(Serial)`?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Actually, I have no idea about this sentence. This is the first time I see something like this means to use "Serial" directly and we can parse incoming string or data.

Comment: What kind of JSON do you expect to receive? Always an object with 3 key-value pairs of type string, but unknown key names?

Comment: @gre_gor As I mentioned above means an object with 3 key-value pairs of type string. There is no key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. I'm using the extra key name.

So, my modified serial data string now looks like:

```
{"ActionOne":"ONE","TPS":"0.40","MAP":"0.95","LOAD":"14"}
{"ActionTwo":"TWO","LOAD":"2.40","RPM":"4200","INJECTION_TIME":"4.87"}
```

and so now using `containsKey()` function, just check which one is coming. If `ActionOne` is coming then according to that serial data we got. And If `ActionTwo` is coming then according to that serial data we got.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

String response = "";
bool begin = false, finished;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() { 
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;

  while (finished == false)
  {
    if (Serial.available())
    {
      const char in = Serial.read();
      if (in == '{')
      {
        response = "";  // Blank the string
        begin = true;
      }
      if (begin)
      {
        response += (in); // Only write if within the {}
      }
      if (in == '}')
      { 
        begin = false;   // Prevent any chars between } and { leaking through.
        break;
      }
    }
    delay(1);
  }

  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);

  const char* ActionOne = root["ActionOne"];
  const char* ActionTwo = root["ActionTwo"];

  if(root.containsKey("ActionOne"))
  {
    float TPS = root["TPS"];
    float MAP = root["MAP"];
    int LOAD = root["LOAD"];

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(TPS);

    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print(MAP);

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(LOAD);  
  }

  if(root.containsKey("ActionTwo"))
  {
    float LOAD = root["LOAD"];
    int RPM = root["RPM"];
    float INJECTION_TIME = root["INJECTION_TIME"];

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(LOAD);

    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print(RPM);

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(INJECTION_TIME);    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read 3 values of a object that you don't know the names of the key, you can use an iterator as shown in the [ArduinoJson library's docs](https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/doc/decoding/#check-values).

And as already mentioned in the comments, you can also replace all the serial reading code with just `Serial` passed into the `jsonBuffer.parseObject` function.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const struct LCDPos {
  uint8_t x;
  uint8_t y;
} lcd_pos[] = {
  {0, 0},
  {8, 0},
  {0, 1},
};

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(Serial);
  if (root == JsonObject::invalid())
    return;

  uint8_t i = 0;
  for (JsonObject::iterator it = root.begin(); it != root.end() && i<(sizeof(lcd_pos)/sizeof(lcd_pos[0])); ++it, i++)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(lcd_pos[i].x, lcd_pos[i].y);
    lcd.print(it->value.asString());
  }
}
```

You will need to make sure, that the values are sent in the order that you want them on your LCD.

EDIT:
I don't have an LCD screen, so I didn't test the code with an LCD, but the code that just dumps the parsed data back to serial works.

```
//#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const struct LCDPos {
  uint8_t x;
  uint8_t y;
} lcd_pos[] = {
  {0, 0},
  {8, 0},
  {0, 1},
};

//LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(Serial);
  if (root == JsonObject::invalid())
    return;

  Serial.println("JSON received");
  uint8_t i = 0;
  for (JsonObject::iterator it = root.begin(); it != root.end() && i < (sizeof(lcd_pos) / sizeof(lcd_pos[0])); ++it, i++)
  {
    //lcd.setCursor(lcd_pos[i].x, lcd_pos[i].y);
    //lcd.print(it->value.asString());
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(lcd_pos[i].x);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.print(lcd_pos[i].y);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.println(it->value.asString());
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

If I send

```
{"TPS":"0.40","MAP":"0.95","LOAD":"14"}{"LOAD":"2.40","RPM":"4200","INJECTION_TIME":"4.87"}
```

over the serial, it returns

```
JSON received
0:0,0 0.40
1:8,0 0.95
2:0,1 14

JSON received
0:0,0 2.40
1:8,0 4200
2:0,1 4.87
```

Comment: I tried out your code, but nothing is displaying on LCD.

Comment: I don't have an LCD, so I don't know why the LCD doesn't work, but the JSON parsing works.